# JRuby and SQLite3

Tags: jdbc, sqlite, jruby, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to make work JRuby and SQLite3 with the following gems:

> bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
>
> bundler (1.3.2)
>
> dbd-jdbc (0.1.6 java)
>
> dbi (0.4.5)
>
> deprecated (2.0.1)
>
> jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2.1)
>
> jruby-launcher (1.0.15 java)
>
> jruby-openssl (0.8.2)
>
> json (1.7.7 java)
>
> rack (1.5.2)
>
> rack-protection (1.4.0)
>
> rake (10.0.3)
>
> rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
>
> rvm (1.11.3.6)
>
> sinatra (1.3.5)
>
> sqlite3 (1.3.7)
>
> tilt (1.3.5)

and this code:

```
require 'java'
require 'dbi'
require 'dbd/Jdbc'
require 'jdbc/sqlite3'

dbh = DBI.connect(
  "DBI:jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite",  # connection string
   '',                                 # no username for sqlite3
   '',                                 # no password for sqlite3
   'driver' => 'org.sqlite.JDBC')      # need to set the driver
```

But I have this error:

> DBI::InterfaceError: Unable to load driver 'jdbc' (underlying error: wrong constant name jdbc)
>          load_driver at /home/gl/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:300
>      mon_synchronize at /home/gl/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:211
>          load_driver at /home/gl/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:242
>     _get_full_driver at /home/gl/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:160
>              connect at /home/gl/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:145
>               (root) at srv.rb:6

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been trying to work this out myself, and eventually succeeded -  the problem is that the driver name is now 'Jdbc', rather than 'jdbc' - capitalization is important, both in the connection string, and the require statement. If you change your connection string to "DBI:Jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite" it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter#standalone-with-activerecord) rather than DBI.

You can execute bare SQL thus:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
```

Comment: I want to put raw sql queries.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - there are many reasons why someone might choose DBI over ActiveRecord, and plenty of situation in which a direct database access, rather than a heavyweight ORM abstraction would be a prudent choice.

Comment: The question was "have you got an idea?"  So I put forward an idea that's worked for me in similar cases.  Other constraints were not articulated.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work (for me at least). I searched SO and the Web for hours (there's a lot of good and bad information out there) and finally came upon a solution that works (for me at least). A large part of the problem is solved by adding the line 'Jdbc::SQLite3.load_driver'.

```
require 'java'
require 'jdbc/sqlite3'

module JavaSql
  include_package 'java.sql'
end

Jdbc::SQLite3.load_driver
Java::org.sqlite.JDBC

conn_str = 'jdbc:sqlite:../Data/AflBettingHistory.db3'
conn = JavaSql::DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str)
stm = conn.createStatement
rs = stm.executeQuery("select Name from Team")
while (rs.next) do
  puts rs.getString("Name")
end
rs.close
stm.close
conn.close
```